# AWS GetAuthorizationToken error with root user

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cli, amazon-ecr

I am trying to push a docker image to AWS ECR. I am using my root user (I know that it's not recommended).

I created an access key/secret in my local machine. Then I used this command to push it (copied from ECR):

```
sudo aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin xxxxxx.xxxxxx.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

But I keep getting this error!

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetAuthorizationToken operation: User: arn:aws:sts::5555555555555:assumed-role/AmazonEC2RunCommandRoleForManagedInstances/mi-08d61ab572732fec4 is not authorized to perform: ecr:GetAuthorizationToken on resource: * because no identity-based policy allows the ecr:GetAuthorizationToken action
```

I've seen similar posts saying that it's because of the 2FA. I deactivated it, but nothing changed.

Comment: It seems that the user or role you are using to push the image to ECR doesn't have the required permissions. Could you please share the IAM permissions of the user/role?

Comment: @rock'nrolla .. it's the root user. does it need specific permission?

Answer (score 0):

The error clue is in the error message: an AWS role with name  `AmazonEC2RunCommandRoleForManagedInstances` does not have `ecr:GetAuthorizationToken` permissions. Your user permissions do not come into play - you mentioned disabling 2fa, you can enable that again - it is the machine you are on that's automatically supplying AWS credentials to AWS cli, via the medium of IAM role. You have a number of options:

1. Attach an inline or customer managed IAM policy granting `AmazonEC2RunCommandRoleForManagedInstances` role explicit `ecr:GetAuthorizationToken` rights; you would have to create this policy yourself
2. Attach one of the [AWS managed policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/security-iam-awsmanpol.html), ie `AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryPowerUser`  would work. Caveat: all other machines using `AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryPowerUser` IAM role will get the same rights. You can mitigate that by creating a custom role for `mi-08d61ab572732fec4` and granting that new role the new rights
3. If you want to use your own credentials, then set `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` environment variables in the shell of your machine , see these [instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html)

One of these 3 options should do as they involve little administrative effort, though there are others.

Comment: thanks for the info, but I am using the root user! Does this apply to it?

Answer (score 0):

I problem was due to the SUDO command. I just changed the permission of the docker file like:

```
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

And everything started working.